# need help to get a numbers into class using backtesting.py

Tags: python, back-testing

I want to get the best strategy by using sma corssover, I get error when i try to input parameters into the class.

Thanks for helping!

Erorr:  `bt = Backtest(df_tesla, SmaBestVal(x, i), TypeError: Strategy.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'`

```
class SmaBestVal(Strategy):
    def init(self, n1, n2):
        close = self.data.Close
        self.sma1 = self.I(SMA, close, n1)
        self.sma2 = self.I(SMA, close, n2)

    def next(self):
        if crossover(self.sma1, self.sma2):
            self.buy()
        elif crossover(self.sma2, self.sma1):
            self.sell()


all_sma = []
for i in range(100, 210, 10):
    for x in range(10, 75, 5):
        bt = Backtest(df_tesla, SmaBestVal(x, i),
                      cash=10000, commission=.002,
                      exclusive_orders=True)
        all_sma.append(bt.run())

highest_ret = 0
highest_meth = None
for meth in all_sma:
    if highest_ret < meth["Return (Ann.) [%]"]:
        highest_meth = meth
print(highest_meth)
```

I want to get the best strategy by using sma corssover by checking all

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.